# Suppose that $V = R(T) \oplus W$ and $W$ is $T$-invariant. Show that if $V$ is finite-dimensional, then $W = N(T)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Part (a) of the problem has already asked me to prove that $W \subseteq N(T)$.

I did this using the following argument for any arbitray $x \in W$:

1. $T(x) \in W$ since $W$ is $T$-invariant.
2. $W$ is a subspace of $V$, so $x \in V$, so $T(x) \in R(T)$.

Thus, $T(x) \in W$ and $T(x) \in R(T) \to T(x) \in W \cap R(T) \to T(x) = 0 \to x ∈ N(T)$.

However, for showing that $W = N(T)$ I can only think of finding a way to prove the other direction of the subset  relation, that is $N(T)\subseteq W$.

The solution says that by observing that both $W$ and $N(T)$ have the same dimension $= \dim(V) - \dim(R(T))$, and combining it with the conclusion of part(a), it can be concluded that $W = R(T)$.

I can not see why this is true.
The book where this question is from explains that if a subspace of a vector space has equal dimension to it, then the subspace must be equal to the vector space, but in this case it is being applied to two separate subspaces of the same vector space?

Can someone please explain why the solution is true or provide another solution?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Apply the said theorem to the *vector space* $W$ and the subspace $N(T)$ and it'll be clear.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This reminds me that I forgot to mention T is defined as T:V$\to$V. Wouldn't it require N(T) to be the subspace of W?

Comment: oops, my fault: you should apply the theorem to the vector space $N(T)$ to the subspace $W$.

Comment: I see, just to clarify if I understand correctly, N(T) contains the basis for W due to part a, so it must contain its span(that is W) which is a subspace of N(T) with dimension = dim(N(T)). And thus, W = N(T). Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who might be stuck here, here's the solution, thanks to the quick replies.

Let $\beta$ = {$v_1, v_2, v_3, ....., v_k$} be a basis for W.
Observe that $\beta \subseteq$ W $\subseteq$ N(T) and thus, $$\beta \subseteq N(T)$$

Hence, $span(\beta) = W$ is a subspace of N(T).

It now becomes clear that because:

1. W is a subspace of N(T)
2. $dim(W) = dim(N(T)) = dim(V) - dim(R(T))$
   $$W = N(T)$$